# Pull and list most common id inside a flat file database

Tags: linux, database, bash, flat-file

I have a flat file database of twitter ids that are following daesh accounts with just under half a million lines that looks like this:

```
722030494578122752  | User Followes/followed pxayrxxcz
```

When I want to search for an id I just do a simple bash script that looks like this.

```
grep -R $id | sort
```

and that will pull up every daesh account i have scraped that that id follows. I'd like to create another script, the start of which would look something like this.

```
cat * | sort | uniq | othercodehere > mostcommonids.txt
```

What i want to do is to run this script on my database files and have it spit out the, say ten, most common ids that it runs across. id like to have it list how many times the id is come across but i don't know if that is possible.

Here is 8 line example of the database:

```
701719369605222400  | User Follows/followed 2ccdcccdcc
701719369605222400  | User Follows/followed omans_228
701719369605222400  | User Follows/followed Qs_7ii
721205276146343936  | User Follows/followed DDSSW890
712955245035331584  | User Follows/followed dxbdbd54
725779221335912452  | User Follows/followed GAREBSHAMI
713079851499040768  | User Follows/followed oobaida_793
713079851499040768  | User Follows/followed AbuH3
```

So in this case 701719369605222400 (the first three ids) is the most common id in the list, and 713079851499040768 (the two last ids) is the second most common id in the list. Id like the output file to look like this:

```
701719369605222400  3
713079851499040768  2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `uniq -c`:

```
sort file.txt | uniq -c
```

Most common IDs first:

```
sort file.txt | uniq -c | sort -k1,1rn
```

Least common IDs first:

```
sort file.txt | uniq -c | sort -k1,1n
```

---

**Edit:**

Do:

```
grep -o '^[^[:blank:]]\+'  file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr
```

To get the first 2 values:

```
grep -o '^[^[:blank:]]\+'  file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr | tail -2
```

To get proper formatting:

```
grep -o '^[^[:blank:]]\+'  file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr | sed -r 's/^[[:blank:]]+([0-9]+)[[:blank:]]+(.*)$/\2 \1/'
```

Comment: Everything is on the same line so this wouldn't work, it says all ids are listed only once because the user they are following is on the same line as the user's id.

Comment: @Matt Please edit your question to add an example input and your expected output from that..its way better to understand that way..

Comment: Done! sorry bout that.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
awk '{print $1}' * | sort | uniq -c | sort -nrk1,1 | head -n
-- where n = number of top IDs you want to view
```

Example output:
I generated bunch of data files ..

```
$ ls -la
total 44
drwxrwxr-x  2 adesilva adesilva 4096 May  2 22:16 .
drwxrwxrwt. 9 root     root     4096 May  2 22:07 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 adesilva adesilva   54 May  2 22:16 data46
-rw-rw-r--  1 adesilva adesilva   54 May  2 22:16 data47
-rw-rw-r--  1 adesilva adesilva   54 May  2 22:16 data48
-rw-rw-r--  1 adesilva adesilva   54 May  2 22:16 data49
-rw-rw-r--  1 adesilva adesilva   54 May  2 22:16 data50
-rw-rw-r--  1 adesilva adesilva   54 May  2 22:16 data51
-rw-rw-r--  1 adesilva adesilva   54 May  2 22:16 data52
-rw-rw-r--  1 adesilva adesilva   54 May  2 22:16 data53
-rw-rw-r--  1 adesilva adesilva   54 May  2 22:16 data54

$ cat data46 # contents of one sample file. I did minor changes to 
             # simulate your scenario
722030494578122752 | User Followes/followed pxpyrxxcz
```

Shows the top 2 occurring IDs with the count:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' * | sort | uniq -c | sort -nrk1,1 | head -2
      4 722030494578122752
      2 732030494578122752
```

If you want the sort can be executed inside awk, i.e `awk '{print $1 | "sort"}' *`. Also unique can be handled by a reg-ex in awk as well. But it does get bit complicated, the above will do the job and likely bit easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you as well, much easier to see what is going on :)